# SonarQube Duplications on New Code

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

SonarQube Version: 6.7
Language: C#
SCM Sensor: Enabled

I've tried searching around but I haven't gotten any solid answers.

I am attempting to set up a quality gate for duplicate code. While testing I was able to increase my duplicated blocks count for my solution but the "Duplications on New Code" didn't increase so it didn't fail the quality gate. Setting up a static number for the duplicate code count to fall under isn't going to work since there are multiple solutions that are using the same quality gate.

When running the following Sonar command on our build system I am seeing some odd behavior:

```
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"SonarKey" /n:"SonarName" /v:"BuildNumber" /d:sonar.verbose=false /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=**/*.coveragexml
Build Solution
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end
```

I have configured the Leak period to "previous_version", which based on my understanding means that any code added to the project will be considered new code.

Any ideas as to why the duplication's on new code aren't increasing?

Comment: Did you duplicate code inside a project or is the duplicated code spread over several projects?

Comment: Single project - 3 classes